# How to add an extra Row at the End and the Beginning in a Table after Page Break

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

As described above how can I add a Row that is only visible at the End and the Beginning in a Table after a Page Break?

Is there any attribute that I can use for a table row to specify if its the last or first row on a page?

The scenario is that i need the row for calculation the subtotal of one preceding column, but that doesn`t work for me with a table-footer or table-header.

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" margin-top="1cm">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="85%"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="14%"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="1%"/>
                    <fo:table-footer>                         
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-position-within-table="last-ending" retrieve-class-name="subtotal-caption"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:retrieve-table-marker retrieve-position-within-table="last-ending" retrieve-class-name="subtotal"/>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>                                         
                    </fo:table-footer>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="subtotal-caption"/>
                        <fo:marker marker-class-name="subtotal"/>
                        <fo:table-row>  
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right">
                                    EUR
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/document/data/list/invoice/list/position">                                                                          
                            <fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-cell>                             
                                    <fo:marker marker-class-name="subtotal-caption">
                                        Zwischenssumme                                  
                                    </fo:marker>
                                    <fo:block>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="name/text()"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:marker marker-class-name="subtotal">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="amount + sum(preceding::amount/text()) - /document/data/list/invoice/amount/text()"/>
                                    </fo:marker>
                                    <fo:block text-align="right">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(amount/text(), '###.##0,00', 'european')"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:block text-align="left">
                                        <xsl:if test="vat = 1">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="' *'"/>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row> 
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
```

What I want to receive is something like this:

- Pos A - 1 EUR
- Pos B - 2 EUR
- Pos C - 2 EUR
- Subtotal - 5 EUR
- ... next Page

But the current Result is:

- Pos A - 1 EUR
- Pos B - 2 EUR
- Pos C - 2 EUR
- ... next Page

Comment: I have edited your title. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please include actual XSL-FO and XSLT code, perhaps together with a description of how FOP renders the PDF.

Comment: Are you looking into adding margin when a table spills over to the next page?

Comment: Have you tried extension function 'axf:footnote-keep' as described in http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo/axf4-extension.htm#axf.footnote-keep

Comment: @boomchickawah Is your query resolved. Even  I am stuck in the same scenario where i want total amount on every page end.

Comment: @MathiasMüller He wants to get the total of price on every page end so that every page has different total of all the rows present in that specific page. Even i am stuck in the same situation.